# When can spoilers be used on airliners?

Tags: landing, airspeed, spoilers

On airliners, are spoilers used in any part of flight other than landing?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spoilers have many uses, but first I want to distinguish types of spoilers.  Airplanes will typically have ground spoilers and flight spoilers and they work like they sound.

- Ground spoilers only open up on the ground -- these are usually much more detrimental to lift than the flight spoilers.
- Flight spoilers open when actuated by the pilots

Another type of spoiler is the spoileron, which is used on some airplanes like an aileron, that is to bank the airplane by destroying lift on one wing.

Since you ask about use in the air, I will focus on flight spoilers.  When would I use flight spoilers?

- I want to descend faster
- I want to slow down quicker
- I want to descend and slow down

#### I want to descend faster

This can be broken down into three categories

- I screwed up and I need to make a crossing restriction
- The anti/ice system turned on (more on this below)
- I am initiating an emergency descent (abnormal)

The bit about a/ice comes from the fact that on many airplanes when a/ice is on there is a high demand for bleed air.  In the EMB-145 the FADEC bumps up idle thrust quite a bit to meet this demand and if you did not anticipate this in your descent planning, we were authorized to use our spoilers in icing conditions to aid in the descent.  This could be interpreted as an "I screwed up" case, but really isn't in my opinion.

#### I want to slow down faster

If there is a charted speed restriction, this may be useful.  Particularly if you have just prioritized the descent to meet a crossing restriction and now need to bleed off speed.

You might need to start descending out of 10k feet ASAP, and need to be at 250 kts to do so, and in this case spoilers can be useful.

#### I want to descend and slow down

In a jet, this can be hard when clean.  Often the choice is descend **or** slow down.  When you need to do both, spoilers can be a great help.

---

In the case of landing or rejected takeoff, all of the spoilers (including flight spoilers) should deploy automatically on most airplanes when the thrust levers are moved to idle, there is weight-on-wheels and you are above some threshold speed.

In addition, spoilers are useful in some airplanes for roll control, in addition to airplanes with pure spoileron roll control.  I didn't spend much time on this topic as like the ground spoilers in landing and RTO, these are passive from a pilot point of view -- you aren't specifically controlling these spoilers, the flight control system is doing it for you.  In any case, the spoilers used for roll control are quite important during flight.

As you can see, spoilers have many uses in flight and not just for landing.

Comment: Spoilers are also used for roll control (and I'm not talking about spoilerons). See also [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/140/exclusive-use-of-spoilers-for-roll-control-on-a320-on-final-approach)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert: A spoiler that is used for roll control is called a spoileron. Therefore you _are_ talking about spoilerons (unlike flapperon, which is an aileron that also acts as flap, spoileron is any spoiler used for roll control, not an aileron acting a spoiler).

Comment: Normally the same set of surfaces act as both flight and ground spoilers and possibly spoilerons. They just deflect less in flight.

Comment: @JanHudec That depends on the airplane.  In the EMB-145 (I am most familiar with this airplane) the there were separate spoiler panels that only actuated on the ground and were not used at all during flight.  But you are correct that in other aircraft it may just be a mater of max deflection that differentiates the use case.

Comment: @JanHudec No I'm not talking about spoilerons. Many airplanes have normal ailerons but use regular spoilers for roll control in certain phases of flight (like final approach)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert: If spoilerons are spoilers that are used for roll control, the dual function spoilers still fit that definition. Unless you say spoilerons are spoilers that are used _only_ for roll control, which I've not seen in any of the descriptions.

Comment: @JanHudec Correct, and I think we agree, but from a slightly different angle. My interpretation of a spoileron is a spoiler that is the only means to control roll (so without ailerons) and is dedicated to that task. I was referring to regular spoilers that seem to have a multiple functions: create drag, dump lift and roll control (acting as a spoileron).

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Spoilers that are used in conjunction with ailerons during low speed flight are still called spoilerons.  (They are on the Learjets that I used to fly.)

Comment: And what if these spoilerons are also used as "real" spoilers. Are they still called that? Potato Potato :)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert: potayto, potahto... ;) Anyway, Airbus documents don't ever call them spoilerons, for another point of view.

Comment: In my time, oh so long ago, the devices shown in the image accompanying the question were called speed brakes. Don't know what the manuals said. I do know that if you deployed them just a tad on the 727, that gave you extremely responsive ailerons. Always wanted to do that and roll the airplane, but never did.

Comment: @Terry Speed brakes primarily create drag, while spoilers primarily disrupt the ability of the wing to create lift. In practice we use them in the same way, but they accomplish our goal in different ways.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Yes, actually. On the Lear's they were called different things depending on **how** they were being used.  Spoilerons while in the air and assisting roll control, and spoilers when deployed on the ground! :)

Comment: This question is over a year old now, but to your **I want to descend faster** section could be added: _ATC hung me out to dry_ or _ATC forgot about me_ or _ATC..._.

Answer (score 13):

Certainly! Spoilers are used whenever there's a need to descend a little faster than the aircraft will with idle engines and just flying downwards with it's own drag. This happens quite often. Pilots will try to avoid it since it's not efficient use of fuel, but they usually can't in busy airspace where stuff happens quickly and there are fixed procedures to follow.

[image: spoilers]

In fact if I remember correctly, many spoilers don't have speed limits so that they can be used in all stages of flight.

They are also used for rejected takeoffs (RTO). Spoilers work by disabling the lift, so the more they are deployed, the more lift is reduced. This helps the descend, or puts more pressure on the wheels on the ground making the braking action more effective during landings and RTOs, especially when the ground is slippery.